# How can i pass parameter with popup window

Tags: selenium-rc

I need to open a popup with parameter

here am using,

```
selenium.click("img_id")

selenium.open("http://www.olio.combankcustomerlist.action?bankId=116&branchId=33&customerId=1&readOnly=false&display=5")
```

I want to pass these parameters also

When i use this: `selenium.click("img_id")`

I am getting http://www.olio.combankcustomerlist.action?bankId=116&branchId=null&customerId=null&readOnly=false&display=5"

Branch id will be null,

How can i pass parameter with popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more context ? 
From the looks of it, the problem doesn't lie in Selenium RC, but in the link anchored to your "img_id" element.

What URI do you get if you click the link "by hand" (outside of Selenium) ?